# supress zero rows in crosstab crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crosstab

I have crosstab looks like this

```
          Jan           Feb
Emp1      500           600
Emp2      600           700
Emp3       0             0
```

I want to hide the row3 as it has zero values. I have seen in crosstab expret to supress empty rows but that doesn't server the purpose. I want output like this

```
          Jan           Feb
Emp1      500           600
Emp2      600           700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a SQL Expression that returns a NULL:

```
-- {@DB_NULL}
-- Oracle syntax
(
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL
)

-- {@DB_NULL}
-- MS SQL syntax
(
SELECT NULL
)
```

Create a formula field to convert 0 to NULL:

```
-- {@data}
If {table.field}=0 Then
  {@DB_NULL}
Else
  {table.field}
```

Reference this field in your cross-tab instead of `{table.field}`.  You may have to reset the 'suppress empty rows' setting.