# Crystal Reports 2016 crosstab supress rows based on value of specified columns that are conditionally available

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crosstab like this

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3
Row1   1    0    1
Row2   0    1    1
Row3   1    0    0
Row4   0    0    1
```

This is meant for moving stock between warehouse and outlets. So If Col1 shows stock of the Warehouse and Col2 and Col3 are outlets then products from Row2 and Row4 are not available and rows should not be displayed.

However if Col1 and Col2 are Warehouses and Col3 is an outlet then only Row4 is not available and therefore should be supressed.

Warehouses have ID's lesser that X and outlets have ID's higher than X. I have found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128786/supress-zero-rows-in-crosstab-crystal-reports) and tried to apply it by using code:

```
If {Stock}=0 and {VENUE_ID} < X Then
  {%DB_NULL}
Else
  {Stock}
```

But the code only works for Stock where VENUE_ID is lesser than X. As a result the rows are supressed only when all Stock values are equal to 0. 
If there was a way to make all cells in a row show 0 value then the'd be supressed.
Which is the right way, should I carry on this path and try modify code so other cells in a row are dependant on the specified ones or should I look elsewhere?

Is there a better solution for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by modifying the view on SQL server side. Here are the steps in case somebody runs into this same problem:

1. Add another column to the SQL view I was calling from CR. The column stores value of warehouse Stock. Before all stock values for both warehouses and stores were stored in one column.
2. Create a field `{@Warehouse_Stock}` with a code like that:

   ```
   If {Warehouse_Stock}=0 Then
     {%DB_NULL}
   Else
     {Stock}
   ```
3. Add `{@Warehouse_Stock}` field to row group of cross-tab.
4. Create another field `{@Shop_stock}` and add code:

   ```
   If {Stock}=0 Then
     {%DB_NULL}
   ELSE IF {@Warehouse_stock} = 0 THEN
     {%DB_NULL}
   Else
     {Stock}
   ```
5. Add `{@Shop_stock}` to cross-tab as summary field.
6. In Cross-tab Expert go to Customize style tab, select `@Warehouse_stoc` row and check "Hide empty rows" checkbox.

This worked for me. Hope this solution might help somebody else as well.